# How do I activate a click on this hyperlink in VBA?

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, hyperlink, click

After some very kind help, I now have a small piece code to navigate to a website using a VBA module in Excel. It picks out a horse's name in cell A2 which I have the horse Tiger Roll.This is the code:

```
 Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    'make web page visible
    objIE.Visible = True

    'navigate objIE to this web page
    objIE.navigate "https://www.britishhorseracing.com/racing/horses/racehorse-search-results?pagenum=1&q=" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & "&rated=false"

    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

The problem is that I have inspected the page and found the link but for the life of me I just can't write the correct code to activate the link to drill down into the horse's stats.
Can anyone help and maybe explain the way to do it?
Thank you so much in advance,

Comment: "After some very kind help" - please could you accept the answer in that case? And perhaps go through earlier questions and do likewise.

Comment: Here is its previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542391/how-do-i-place-focus-and-click-submit-button-using-vba-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

Use the class name for the result to target the anchor click

```
objIE.document.querySelector(".link-row").click
```

Comment: The issue is that the element is dynamically loaded so first you have to wait, then you can click it.

Comment: I can't test but makes sense @Igor. You need a time out on your loop to avoid potential infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

If your search has only one result the link to the horse details page is the content of the `href` attribute of the only item with `"tr link-row"` classes.
If your search had more results there would be one item for each result of your search, and you can do what you want with them in the same way (you can keep the first or loop through them etc.).

Just keep in mind that these elements are not part of the document at the first moment, because the document will load with its HTML code, which contains scripts that will load other elements, so VBA must wait Internet Explorer to run these scripts.

To go to the details page of the only/first horse in result page, after your code:

```
Dim htmlPage As HTMLDocument
Set htmlPage = objIE.Document

'Page is dynamically populated from script. You have to wait when the horse link gets loaded
Do While htmlPage.getElementsByClassName("tr link-row").Length < 1
    DoEvents
Loop

'Get link (href attribute) and navigate to it
objIE.navigate htmlPage.getElementsByClassName("tr link-row").Item(0).href

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

Be aware that while `InternetExplorer` object is part of `Microsoft Internet Controls` library, `HTMLDocument` is part of `Microsoft HTML Object Library`, so add it to references in VBA.

Comment: Guys.....thankyou so much for your input! This forum is great and the genuine help that experienced coders give us newbies puts great faith in people. Thankyou so much again!

Comment: remember you can choose an answer to mark as "it works for my question" or vote up every useful answer